# How to create a progressbar not knowing the total iterations?

Tags: python, progress-bar

I am trying to develop a crawler function to collect all the pagination links from Indeed to further use in my Scraper program.

```
# This function take a list of indeed pagination links grabbed in previous function to iterate and
# return a list with all the pagination links
def crawlPagination(url_list):
        pages= url_list
        for page in pages:
           urls_in_page = # Function to get pagination from individual page
           for url in urls_in_page:
               if url not in pages: pages.append(url) 
        return pages
```

I am trying to make a progressbar to show in the terminal, but i dont know how many iterations will it take to grab all links, as some pages have more results then others. Is there a way i can make this?

Comment: How can you have a meaningful progress bar when you don't know how long the code will run for? That just doesn't make sense.

Comment: Eventually you could rely on an estimation, depending on how you collected urls (maybe you can have the size of the file located at some URL and you could add them up to know the total file size, or number of characters, or lines to explore).